# Is it okay to move answer given by the author in the question into a real answer?

Tags: discussion, edits

While I was cleaning some tags, I've edited this post on SO: [How to change sign of a .BLOCK or .WORD in Pep8 (Assembly)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19994134/how-to-change-sign-of-a-block-or-word-in-pep8-assembly)

The author (clearly inactive today) has resolved the problem himself and gave the answer by editing the question instead of creating a real answer. I have taken the liberty to edit his post, remove the useless tag I spotted before, and remove the answer of the question. Then I've posted the response as a real answer. I've put the post in "community wiki" mode, to avoid to gain reputation for an answer I didn't give...

Is it okay to do that? After all, my action was for improving the quality of SO, but it could be frowned upon for some reasons...

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can do that.

I removed the meta commentary from your answer, and made it present tense.  Community Wiki is a nice gesture.

Having it as an answer removes it from the "unanswered questions" pile (when it gets at least one upvote), and puts a count of 1 in column showing the number of answers it has received, so that people can see in the question indexes that it has  been answered.

Comment: Indeed, I didn't think at the "Unanswered" pile... So good practice, in community wiki to avoid confusion :) Thanks.